# change CURLOPT_URLi to input

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm a beginner, I want to ask how to make a nik check CURLOPT_URL https://indonesian-identification-card-ktp.p.rapidapi.com/api/check?nik=5765745456745454
into from input and displays the data, thank you

```
php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://indonesian-identification-card-ktp.p.rapidapi.com/api/check?nik=5765745456745454",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "X-RapidAPI-Host: indonesian-identification-card-ktp.p.rapidapi.com",
        "X-RapidAPI-Key: 313121212"
    ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$array_response = json_decode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
// var_dump($array_response);
$result = $array_response['results']['realtime_data']['data']['findNikSidalih'];
$parse = $array_response['results']['parse_data'];
```

Comment: can you please add more details, it's not very clear what you are trying to achieve here ?

Answer (score 0):

By *from input* I suppose you mean getting the NIK to be searched from a user input like an HTML form.

The following code displays said HTML form and after submitting the form the entered NIK will be found in $_POST['nik'] (where 'nik' is the name of the corresponding input field inside the form). $_POST['nik'] will then be sanitized into $nik (to make sure it only contains numbers) and $nik will then be appended to the URL.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    NIK: <input type="text" name="nik" placeholder="Enter NIK" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<div>
    <pre>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['nik'])) {
    //Make sure it's numbers only or do some other form of sanitizing
    $nik = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $_POST['nik']);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://indonesian-identification-card-ktp.p.rapidapi.com/api/check?nik={$nik}",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "X-RapidAPI-Host: indonesian-identification-card-ktp.p.rapidapi.com",
            "X-RapidAPI-Key: 313121212"
        ],
    ]);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    $array_response = json_decode($response, true);
    var_dump($array_response);
}
?>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Hope that this will get you started.

Side note: Using

```
json_decode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

makes no sense, as json_decode expects ?bool (and not some flag) as the second parameter. Since JSON_PRETTY_PRINT evaluates to (int)128, it will be treated as true (without strict typing).